# How to mock a generator in python

Tags: python

I have a generator that `yields a string` value and in my main app.py I utilize them.

Now I would like to create pytest and try to create a patch for this generator, I have no luck. Can anyone suggest a better working approach? I'm followed the StackOverflow previous question and solution but still didn't manage to get it done.

```
def test_index_route():
    with patch("main._method") as mock_method:
        mock_method.iter.return_value = iter(['1234'])
        response = app.test_client().get('/')

        assert response.status_code == 200
        assert response.data.decode('utf-8') == 'hello world version 1234.'
```

this gives assert failed as
`E assert "hello wo R...0854476448'>." == 'hello world version 1234.'`
`hello world version <MagicMock name='_version_if_file_exists().__next__()' id='140400854476448'>.`

Comment: Dupe? [How to mock generators with mock.patch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36165929/674039)

Comment: `mock_method.iter.return_value = ['1234']`

Answer (score 1):

`mock.method.return_value = iter(['1234'])`

This is a lie, but Python treats generators and functions that return an iterator the same way.